# ImportError: cannot import name '_worker_manager_loop'

Tags: python, python3

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 4, in <module>
    import data
  File "D:\EDSR-PyTorch-master\src\data\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from dataloader import MSDataLoader
  File "D:\EDSR-PyTorch-master\src\dataloader.py", line 17, in <module>
    from torch.utils.data.dataloader import _worker_manager_loop
ImportError: cannot import name '_worker_manager_loop'
```

超解像のネットワークのトレーニングを実行しようとしています．
URL:https://github.com/thstkdgus35/EDSR-PyTorch
上記のエラー文が表示されます．
調べてみたところ，ファイル名が重複しているなどの似たようなエラーについてでてきましたが
あてはまらないと思いました．そこで助けが必要です．

Comment: どなたかから翻訳編集リクエストを頂いていますが、もしこれが質問者さん本人であればログインして頂ければ自由に編集が可能です。もし上手くログインできない際は[ヘルプ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts)をご覧ください。質問を日本語で続けたいかは質問者さんにしか分からないため、質問の和訳編集は原則質問者さんご本人にお願いしています。

Comment: 翻訳編集がなされてしまいました。kakikukekoさん、もしこのまま日本語で質問を続けたいということであればコメントを頂ければと思います。

Comment: Issue にも投稿されていました (同じ方?): https://github.com/thstkdgus35/EDSR-PyTorch/issues/98

Answer (score 1):

この問題は EDSR-PyTorch のこの issue で議論されました: https://github.com/thstkdgus35/EDSR-PyTorch/issues/98

エラーの原因は、PyTorch v1.0rc0 から内部実装が変わり、`torch.utils.data.dataloader._worker_manager_loop` が[削除された（名前が変わった）](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/commit/04f381650e8cabe55305bd04706446f2af296816#diff-724910f4a1ffa1852a02e149b181ac22)ことです。もともと EDSR-PyTorch は PyTorch >=0.4.0 でテストされており、実際 0.4.0 では上手く動いていたようですが、PyTorch 側の変更に追従しておらず、今回の ImportError に繋がったようです。

これに伴って EDSR-PyTorch 側で PyTorch 1.0.0 に追従する[変更が行われた](https://github.com/thstkdgus35/EDSR-PyTorch/commit/9a9d7d74a5a7e010e34bc9784f0e83d6055d85e7)ので、現在の最新版 EDSR-PyTorch を使えばこのエラーは起こらなくなるはずです。また 0.4.0 時代のコードが legacy ブランチに残っているので、PyTorch >=0.4.0 && <1 を使いたい場合はそちらを使うこともできます。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます．
その通りでした．
pytorchのどちらのバージョン（0.4.0，1.0.0）でも利用できました．
ありがとうございます．

Comment: @user31600 質問時のアカウントと異なるようですが、2つのアカウントを作成してしまった場合はヘルプを参考にしてアカウントのマージをしてみてください。 - https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts